# cornerstone: convert page coordinate to canvas coordinate

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, cornerstone

It seems cornerstone is using a different canvas coordinate compared to page coordinate. For example, when I move the mouse right upon the left corner of the rectangle, its position (x,y) is not equal to (xmin, xmax).
How can I convert it?

ps: I saw a function pixelToCanvas() in cornerstone, not sure how to use it or if it's the right direction?

Comment: cornerstone works in the image coordinate system: https://github.com/chafey/cornerstone/wiki/pixel-coordinate-system use pageToPixel() to convert page coordinates to pixel coordinates

Comment: Thanks very much.

Comment: @ChrisHafey hey, I have another question, can you help it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42145454/cornerstone-tools-does-it-support-only-allow-drawing-in-certain-region-of-the-c

Comment: Chris's answer above should be the answer for this question.  Thanks Chris!